# Database field in IN condition

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I'm trying to use a database field in a IN sql condition. My field is a string of values separated by a comma (like this `it,en,fr,de`) and I have to use it in a WHERE clause like this:

`WHERE d.iso639code = c.main_language_isocode OR d.iso639code IN (c.available_language_isocode)`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with FIND_IN_SET

```
WHERE d.iso639code = c.main_language_isocode OR 
FIND_IN_SET(d.iso639code, c.available_language_isocode)
```